# Simple migration of data from SQL to MongoDB using Pentaho

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, database-migration

I am a newbie to Mongodb and Pentaho, I am facing trouble to convert my existing RDBMS table to mongodb.

The structure of RDBMS is:

```
user_id,question_id,option_id
12,23,4
12,24,7
12,24,8
12,25,9
```

I want this to be converted into:

```
{
    user_id:12,
    questions:[
                   {question_id:23,Options:[4]},
                   {question_id:24}, Options:[7,8]},
                   {question_id:25},Optioins:[9]
              ]
}
```

I am using pentaho mongodbOutput, I tried various combinations but none worked.
One of the combination I have used is below

```
user_id,,Y,N,Y,N/A,Insert&Update
question_id,Questions[0],Y,N,N,$push,Insert&‌​Update
options_id,Questions[1],Y,N,N,$push,Insert&Update
```

with this above settings I have got

```
{
    user_id:12,
    questions:[
                   {question_id:23,Options:4},
                   {question_id:24}, Options:7},
                   {question_id:24}, Options:8},
                   {question_id:25},Options:9
              ]
}
```

But I need Options 7,8 to be array.

Comment: Is your problem in transforming the data, or in storing it to mongodb?

Comment: storing it to mongodb

Comment: And how is your structure going in to the MongoDB step, and how are your Mongo Document fields options?

Comment: user_id,,Y,N,Y,N/A,Insert&Update<br>question_id,Questions[0],Y,N,N,$push,Insert&Update<br>options_id,Questions[1],Y,N,N,$push,Insert&Update

Comment: Please add this to your question correctly formatted, or else it is impossible to solve this.

Comment: I updated my question, Please check now.

Comment: With your data I get 4 lines in mongo. You have not included all information necessary to recreate your situation. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve